# Change image for Map aonnation view in rubymotion

Tags: rubymotion

I want to change UIAnnotationView image on mapkit in rubymotion language.

Any one know this, kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

How about a complete working example?  I just tested it :)

A budy and I converted a LOT of iOS code from the iOS Cookbook to RubyMotion

There's a whole chapter on Maps, but the one that looks to answer your question best is this:

https://github.com/IconoclastLabs/rubymotion_cookbook/tree/master/ch_6/06_custompins

It's just like colored pins, but your main difference will be this

```
pinImage = UIImage.imageNamed("ilpin.png")
annotationView.image = pinImage
```

Goodluck! - Gant from Iconoclast Labs

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean, an MKAnnotationView?  If so, you just need to set the image property to a new UIImage.  See this Gist:

https://gist.github.com/3049611

Based on the RubyMotionSamples Beer project - https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/blob/master/Beers/app/beer_map_controller.rb

I have added a new image file called 'signpost.png' under 'resources', and altered the code from using a pin to using a straight up annotation, with the new custom image.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine to change the UIAnnotationView's image

```
         view = MKAnnotationView.alloc.initWithAnnotation(annotation, reuseIdentifier:ViewIdentifier)
         view.image = UIImage.imageNamed("ptr.jpg")
         view.canShowCallout = true
```

I have saved the image ptr.jpg in resources folder.